# performSegue: missing argument for parameter 'sender'

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

Does anybody knows why I get this error in my function? I searched on the web, but nobody had a solution. In the line of my Identifier "goToHome" Xcode shows me the error. If someone could help me I would be very very thankful.

```
@IBAction func signInButtonTrapped(_ sender: UIButton) { if let email = emailTextField.text, let passwort =   passwortTextField.text { if isSignIn {
    Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: passwort) {   (user, error) in

    if let u = user {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
    } else {         //Error
```

Comment: Instead of `sender: self`, try `sender: nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem `self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)` is likely called from a background thread. All UI operations must be performed on the main thread's queue. You should call the main thread inside your closure like this -

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    if let u = user {
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
    } else { }
}
```